# Kotlin: Java type mismatch, use explicit cast

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to create a basic pie chart in Android through the AnyChart library following this link's tutorial: https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android/wiki/Getting-started

However, I am using Kotlin whereas the example uses Java.

I receive the following error in my Android program:

```
Java type mismatch expected (Mutable)List<DataEntry!>! but found kotlin.collections.ArrayList<ValueDataEntry /* = java.util.ArrayList<ValueDataEntry> */. Use explicit cast!
```

Below is my code (the error happens on the **last line**):

```
val pie = AnyChart.pie()
val data = ArrayList<ValueDataEntry>()
data.add(ValueDataEntry("John", 10000))
data.add(ValueDataEntry("Jake", 12000))
data.add(ValueDataEntry("Peter", 18000))
pie.data(data);
```

How would i go about casting the variable `data` to `(Mutable)List<DataEntry!>!`?

Comment: `val data = ArrayList<ValueDataEntry>()` should be `val data = ArrayList<DataEntry>()`. Same generic type as in the Java example.